# Return a $firebaseArray of objects that contain a sub-value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I want to return a $firebaseArray of records that contain a particular value without knowing the parent ID.

[image: Firebase db]

So in this case, I want to get all the objects under 'challenges' that contain the ID pictured above starting with LNF.

I have tried using orderByChild and equalTo, but again this seems to requiring knowing the parent ID. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything with key `CPjip3tVE1Q067Qzx6p0vij0k1|1`try this:

```
var key = "CPjip3tVE1Q067Qzx6p0vij0k1|1";

for child in snapshot.children {
    if child.key == key {
        get your data
    }
}
```

You can use that to loop over all of the children under `"challenges"`

Comment: Hi, I actually want every parent key with the child key starting with LNF, as in the picture above.

Comment: Again I don't know what language you're using so just do something like if key.startsWith("LNF") then get your data. I don't think you'll be able to get those keys in a more efficient manner. You should probably be storing your data differently such as challenges -> key -> LNF -> everything you want.